# Random "github" folder under browser in File Explorers in Remix IDE

Tags: github, ide, ethereum, solidity, remix

Why do I get this random folder named "github" under browser in File Explorers in Remix IDE? It wasn't there when I started using Remix IDE but after a month or two it just appeared. I can't delete it or do anything with it. It's empty and I tried restarting Remix and deleting every project and starting over but that didn't help. I have provided a picture below so you can see what I am talking about. I hope that somebody has encountered this problem but I can't find any solution online. Thanks in advance!
[Random github folder under browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b7Hu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github appears if you have imported some github based library like Openzeppelin in your smart sontract. However, if you remove the import from your code, the folder should automaticallly go away. Sometime remix act weirdly - and continues showing empty github folder. Try clearing browser cache/history/cookies and reload remix, it should reset to default.

Otherwise an empty github folder is harmless and you can safely ignore it.